# Subtracting time values in Excel - If sum is less than one hour it automatically adds 12 hours to sum

Tags: microsoft-excel

A team of our uses an Excel spreadsheet for their timesheets and uses the 12-hour format.

When inputting time worked if the time is says 2:15 PM - 1:30pm, the sum should be :45 however, for some reason Excel will only show it as 12:45.

This isn't an AM/PM problem as I've triple checked that already.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Format the result cell as "General" and multiply the result by 1440.

[image]